# How to calculate NDCG of a classification?

Tags: r, model-evaluation

The NDCG definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain

Suppose I have a classification to classify 3 classes A, B and C, and the result is:

```
  A B C
A 4 5 6
B 7 2 6
C 5 3 8
```

The row is true class and the column is prediction, the accuracy is (4+2+8)/sum_of_all and it is ~ 0.30

My question is, given this result, how could I  compute NDCG score for this?

If possible, please suggest me R code also.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Note that this site is not intended to be a source for advice on coding or software-specific questions. To the extent that people are willing to help you calculate this metric independently of R, you may get a response.

Comment: Hi @DJohnson, thank you very much for your comment. I don't ask about R (I put "if possible", and it does not matter), but I hope if someone can tell me the way to calculate NDCG with a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

NDCG is not a metric for classification accuracy but for ranking accuracy. NDCG compares two ranked lists, the predicted one and the true one. In your case, since we don't know what the classes mean, NDCG is not applicable.